# Puppeteer Constantly Check for Selector to Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, ui-automation, puppeteer

I have been working on a Puppeteer system to help me handle my automation testing. However, my page would prompt a random pop-up to notify customers of on-going promotions - This prevents my test from proceeding. My initial thought was to run a endless loop in the background during the test to `waitForSelector` and click if it exists. However, I was thinking that this approach doesn't sound too smart, and I couldn't find anything suitable in the API.

Has anyone encountered the similar problem and has come out with a brilliant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the popup is always going to appear towards the beginning of the session, you can use [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
await page.waitForSelector('#popup', {visible: true});
await page.click('#popup'); // Close Popup
```

Alternatively, if the element is dynamically added to the page and might not appear, you can use the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface to watch for the element to be added to the DOM tree and click it:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes[i].id === 'popup' && window.getComputedStyle(mutation.addedNodes[i]).display !== 'none') {
          mutation.addedNodes[i].click(); // Close Popup
        }
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(document, {subtree: true});
});
```